# Log4J Issue in Grails app which has a dependency on comons-logging

Tags: grails, log4j

I am adding a dependency to my Grails Project which brings in both commons-logging and log4j as transitive dependencies. When I run my app I then get an error

```
Error Error executing script RunApp: Could not initialize class
org.apache.log4j.LogManager (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see 
entiretrace.) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class 
org.apache.log4j.LogManager
```

I tried to remove the commons-logging dependency as per [this link](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/04/logging-dependencies-in-spring/) by excluding the commons-logging. But it never helped. I see that commons-logging is not a direct dependency of the dependency I am adding. So if do

```
    runtime ('com.company.i18n:i18n:1.3.4')
    { 
        excludes 'commons-logging'
    }
```

does it exclude all the commons-logging dependencies in my dependency ? Or only the immediate ones. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried hard by excluding "log4j" from all the dependencies, but nothing worked. Finally I solved this by avoiding all the transitive dependencies and then adding what ever was necessary.

```
//add necessary dependencies.

runtime ('com.company.i18n:i18n:1.3.4')
{ 
    transitive = false
}
```

Comment: thanks this also solved the conflict between grails and xmlapis for me! It was driving me nuts till I saw this which finally worked! Added this to build.groovy --> runtime ('xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04')
       {
        transitive = false
       }